# ¿Como validar un dato de un csv con un input text, con javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv

Soy nuevo en desarrollo web, seguramente lo que esté preguntando sea muy simple pero no encuentro un a solución clara.

Tengo un archivo .csv de una sola columna con puros números en la ruta doc/series.csv de lado del servidor, y desde un javascript quiero leerlo para que luego mediante un input text pueda verificar si existe o no un número del .csv.

Necesito saber como puedo leer el csv y hacer la consulta mediante javascript.

este es el codigo

```
<label>Número de Serie del Producto <button id="btnvalidar" 
onclick="buscar()">VALIDAR NÚMERO DE SERIE</button><span style="padding- 
right:5px; padding-left:5px;" id="mensaje"></span><br>
   <span><input type="number" name="numero_serie" id="mySerie" value="" 
 size="40" placeholder="Escribe Aquí"></span></label>

<ul id="serieList" style="display: none;" >
<li>12345678</li>
</ul>


var buscar = function() {
var text;    
var serie = document.getElementById("mySerie").value;
if(!serie.replace(/\s+/g,'')) {//remove blank spaces
text = "Ingrese la serie";
    document.getElementById("mySerie").value = "";
    document.getElementById("register").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('mySerie').style.border = 'thick solid red'
    document.getElementById('mensaje').style.float= 'right';
    document.getElementById('mensaje').style.color= '#fff';
    document.getElementById('mensaje').style.background= 'red';
//alert('Movie name required !');
document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = text;
return;
}
serie = serie.toUpperCase();
var list = document.getElementById('serieList');
list = list.getElementsByTagName('li');//movie title list
var i = list.length, html, flag = false, matches = [];
while(i --) {//walk through the list
  html = list[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase();//get the movie in the li
  if(-1 !== html.indexOf(serie)){//-1, string not found
    flag = true;
    matches.push(html);
  }
}
if(!flag) {
  text = "Serie no válida";
      document.getElementById("mySerie").value = "";
      document.getElementById("register").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById('mySerie').style.border = 'thick solid red'
      document.getElementById('mensaje').style.float= 'right';
      document.getElementById('mensaje').style.color= '#fff';
      document.getElementById('mensaje').style.background= 'red';
} else {
  text = "Serie válida";
      document.getElementById("register").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('mySerie').style.border = 'thick solid #A5DF00'
      document.getElementById('mensaje').style.float= 'right';
      document.getElementById('mensaje').style.color= '#fff';
      document.getElementById('mensaje').style.background= '#a5df00';
}
document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = text;
```

};

Comment: primero debes mejorar la pregunta para que te puedan ayudar, por ejemplo debes mostrar el código que llevas y hasta donde llegaste... ya que  lo que preguntas es muy amplio: inputs, files, strings... Por otro lado si no tienes còdigo puedes empezar buscando en google como leer un archivo  con js desde un input y cuando tengas un avance arreglas tu pregunta. Acá puedes ver algo de eso https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications